# Escape a regular expression using sed

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I'm trying to use SED to delete lines inside a log file containing the word "DEBUG". 
DEBUG can be :

- The first word of the line.
- A word inside the line surrounded with at least one space.

The following regex works fine :

```
(?m)( |^)DEBUG\s
```

But when I try to use it with sed, there is no effect.

```
sed '/(?m)( |^)DEBUG\s/d' infile.log > result.txt
```

I tried to escape somme characters like () or \ or even ^ but without any success.
Thanks for your help.

For example, I have a file containing :

```
...
DEBUG aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
DEBUG bbbbbbbb bbb bbbb 
ccc cccDEBUGcccc cccc cc
dddDEBUG dddd ddd
DEBUGeeee eee eeee
fff fff fff fff ff DEBUG fff
...
```

So the result expected should be :

```
...
DEBUG aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
DEBUG bbbbbbbb bbb bbbb 
fff fff fff fff ff DEBUG fff
...
```

But instead, all lines appears in the result file.

Comment: sed won't support inline modifiers

Comment: [mcve] You should give 2-3 simplified input examples which should match, 2-3 which shouldn't, and what you like to get as result and what you get instead.

Comment: Did you try pimping `sed`'s regexp version (by giving option `-r` for regexp-extended)?

Comment: You could probably use `grep` for this if you just want to remove specific lines: `grep -v -P '(?m)( |^)DEBUG\s' < infile > outfile`

Comment: Thanks Alfe. Finally I use grep instead of sed as you mention it and it works fine.

Comment: This would also work (however not super portable): `sed '/^DEBUG /d;/ DEBUG /d' infile`

Comment: With gnu sed : sed '/\bDEBUG/!d' infile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you actually do not need a `sed` command here. A egrep command can solve your problem.

```
 egrep " \DEBUG|^DEBUG\ " infile.log > result.txt
```

Now your output file result.txt would be look like below:-

```
DEBUG aaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
DEBUG bbbbbbbb bbb bbbb 
fff fff fff fff ff DEBUG fff
```